# Load a html page into a div for jqueryui dialog and editing the contents

Tags: jquery

I have a Html page i'm loading into a jquery ui dialog, I need to insert a session id into the static loaded html for the page onload processing.  My first thought was to use  .Data() and add in the var that way but I don't think it's possible on a .Load(page.html) call?

So I have tried to do this a lot of different ways but here is the gyst:

```
<div id="cs0" title ="Add/Edit Licence periods"></div>
$('#cs0').hide();

//load the page into the the div
$('#cs0').load("/Periods.html");

//edit inner html of one of the divs in the loaded page
$('#cs0').innerHTML.getElementById("MyDiv").innerHTML = sessionid;

$('#il0').click(function () {
    $('#cs0').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        maxWidth: 1000,
        maxHeight: 800,
        width: 700,
        height: 300,
        modal: true,
    });
});
```

I have also tried using data, but can't get this to work :( any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it's not an iframe in the content you can do this:

```
$('#cs0').load("/Periods.html", function() { 
    $('#cs0').find('#MyDiv').html(sessionid);
});
```

Remember the find function takes a selector, so `MyDiv` is not valid obviously. You need a proper selector like a class or an id.

Answer (score 1):

To get the `innerHTML` of the loaded HTML file, you would use:

```
$('#cs0')[0].innerHTML;
```

However, that's not what you want to do apparently. You want:

```
$('#cs0').find("#MyDiv").html(sessionid);
```

This should all definitely go inside a callback for the `load()` method, that way you know the data is there.

```
$('#cs0').load('/Periods.html', function() {
    $(this).find("#MyDiv").html(sessionid);
});
```

[jsFiddle: A similar situation with assumed markup](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/XgdyY/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a callback on `.load("/Periods.html");`

That callback should be a function that does

> $('#cs0').innerHTML.getElementById("MyDiv").innerHTML = sessionid;

I didn't test this but it should be something like this

```
$('#cs0').load('/Periods.html', function() {
   $('#cs0').innerHTML.getElementById("MyDiv").innerHTML = sessionid;
});
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Without the callback the .load() will execute asynchronously, meaning that it won't wait till it loads the page before it goes on to the next chuck of code. Thus it wouldn't know what's there.

Comment: Upvote thankyou! also thankyou for the most detailed answer with regards to the callbacks.

Comment: I did, just couple months late ;)